# IAM & Cross-account write to S3 bucket: Allow service principal based on organisation ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I have many AWS accounts. I enabled VPC flow logs to all of them, and I want to ship those logs to a central S3 bucket in my Log Archive Accounts.

An IAM policy that works is the following:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryWrite",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"},
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::central_log_archive_bucket",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:SourceAccount": <account_id-1>,
                "aws:SourceAccount": <account_id-2>,
                "aws:SourceAccount": <account_id-3>,
                ...
                "aws:SourceAccount": <account_id-N>
            },
            "ArnLike": {
                "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:*:<account_id-1>:*",
                "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:*:<account_id-2>:*",
                "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:*:<account_id-3>:*",
                ...
                "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:logs:*:<account_id-N>:*",

            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanna simplify this. Instead of adding all account IDs like shown above, I wanna allow ANY VPC service that belongs in an AWS account under my organization to publish logs to the S3. In short, I want to do something like:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryWrite",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {"Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"},
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::central_log_archive_bucket",
        "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "ID"
         }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am seeing the following error message:

`Unsupported Condition Key for Service Principal`

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks.html,

You can't use some condition keys with certain service principals. For example, you can't use the `aws:PrincipalOrgID` condition key with the service principal `cloudfront.amazonaws.com.` or other service like logs. You should remove condition keys that do not apply to the service principal in the Principal element.

You can automate it with a lambda in each account creation for example, to change the bucket policy...